# Javascript replace url with string

Tags: javascript, url

I have a string of url encoded characters.

wondering if there is a javascript function that can replace all the url encoded characters with normal string characters.

i know i can use the replace function, but it only replaces one certain character an not all at once

for example, I am looking for one function that will replace all the url encoded characters in this string:

```
string urlEncoded = '1%20day%20%40work!%20Where%20are%20you%3F'
```

and give me this string:

```
string replaced = '1 day @ work! Where are you?'
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use decodeURIComponent(string) for that purpose.

```
string urlEncoded = '1%20day%20%40work!%20Where%20are%20you%3F';
string replaced = decodeURIComponent(urlEncoded);
alert(replaced);
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: Please refrain from linking to w3school, see http://w3fools.com for why. The page you link to *might* have correct information, but the site is full of incorrect and misleading information, and linking to the site gives them credibility they do **not** deserve

Comment: You are right @freefaller, I checked the information so that it was correct before posting but it was mainly laziness from my side that I took the first hit on Google. Updated to a link on Mozilla Developer Network instead that has the same info.

Comment: If you have Google account then you should be able to block all results from them, problem solved! (**If** you have a Google account)

Comment: Good idea, added it to my blocklist :)

Comment: Yes if you encoded string have encoded spaces (%20) or newlines (%0D%0A) the will be properly decoded.

Answer (score 0):

```
string replaced = decodeURIComponent(urlEncoded);
```

There is also just `decodeURI` but this does not cope with "special" characters, such as & ? ! # etc

Answer (score 0):

Use decodeURIComponent(urlEncoded)

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for `unescape`

```
var decoded = unescape(urlEncoded);
```

Comment: escape()/unescape() shouldn't be used for URIs though, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent for more information about this.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren: Now, he is not mentioning URLs anywhere, is he?

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren: *URL encoding* is the encoding technique, it does not in any way mean that he is encoding URLs. In fact it seems pretty clear from the example that he is encoding a generic string.